# Entity Framework Code First Set Foreign Key Name

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first

I have two tables:

User
ID
Email

Task
Email
TaskName

The user can have multiple tasks. I need to specify that Email is the foreign key relationship between my task and email table. How can this be done?

Here is my code:

```html
        public MyDataContext() : base("Default")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Task> Tasks { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                .ToTable("User").HasRequired(m => m.Tasks)
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey(m => m.Email)
                    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Task>()
                .ToTable("Task");
        }
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out? I'm having the same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59363602).

Comment: I just created the database table and assigned the primary key, using the designer.

Comment: I see. Using the designer, I was able to apply a custom name to my foreign key. Pity. I was hoping for a way to do it with Code First Migrations, using the Fluent API.